# Is there any way to get a secure URL after redirects?

Tags: php, jquery, get

I am building a shopping cart front and am at an impasse with this problem:

The secure side of the shopping cart is hosted on another site, and I need to be able to get access to their PHP GET variables that are placed in two places:

1. In the url
2. In the page itself under a meta tag.

The only problem, as I was going to do this with an iframe src, is that the variables are generated after a page redirect from the url supplied. For instance, I give the browser:

```
https://www.domain.com/file.php
```

and the page will redirect to:

```
https://www.domain.com/file2.php?CFTOKEN=231351332&CFID=23423235
```

I need to get those two PHP GET variables, but I cannot do it through an iframe because of access-control-point-origin. I also cannot do it through `fopen`, `file_get_contents`, or cURL getting source code because it times out.

How can I do this? It doesn't seem like it would be that difficult.

If I could get access to the URL or the source code I could accomplish this.

Comment: If this is what the provider of this shopping cart solution(?) thinks is the way such thinks should be done … then you should look for another one. Or look through their API documentation again – perhaps they have a _real_ way of doing this that you have not found yet.

Comment: I am actually building this on top of what they already have in place since they are afraid of change, and the cart system that they have now looks terrible. They don't have an API, I just need those two variables to send cart updates to the existing system. They are using PHP GET variables instead of PHP SESSIONs to maintain their cart, so I need some way to read the source code or something.

Comment: There is no way of accessing data from different domains client-side (Same Origin Policy) – unless maybe both sides “agree” on a method, f.e. using postMessage to communicate between window instances holding content from different origins.

Comment: How about server-side through PHP?

Answer (score 1):

if you really have access to both sides you can use web messaging, so after you iframe loaded you can ask it for variables ;)

A simple example of code is here http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/window-postmessage-messagechannel/

Comment: I don't have any way to edit the code of the shopping cart pages, only my storefront pages.